# How do I make a chrome extension manifest v3 service worker reactivate to field port messages?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm having quite a time trying to get the service worker in the chrome extension I'm developing to reactivate when it is sent messages over a long-lived connection a la https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#connect -- I am using the code from this page for a long-lived messaging port almost exactly. The site seems to imply that message passing is an event type that service workers are activated for such that they may handle them, but my service worker just goes inactive after a moment and then my content scripts cannot send messages over the port to that service worker successfully. Specifically, I am using, as per the doc's recommendation, `chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(...)` -- How can I get my service worker to activate and field these messages when appropriate? Moreover, what "events", specifically, cause a chrome extension service worker to reactivate such that they can perform intended tasks pursuant to intended chrome extension functionality?

Thanks very much,
Walt

Comment: The example should work so the explanation for the observed behavior is either a bug in Chrome or you did it incorrectly. The question is not really answerable without [MCVE](/help/mcve) which typically should include manifest.json and describe where each posted fragment runs or how it was executed if it's specified in manifest.json. As for events, all `chrome` API events wake the worker just like they did wake the nonpersistent background script in ManifestV2, nothing's changed.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior. Code works fine in V2, but in V3 the chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(...) function on my service worker never fires.